# How do I debug Trace/BPT Trap errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

How does one go about debugging Trace/BPT Trap errors in Rails? I get no log output, no server output...nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you could clarify if your question it might be easier to get a more specific answer that can help you, but for general debugging in Rails I use the amazing [Pry](http://pry.github.com/) Gem
There are also plenty of Pry Plugins that you can add to make it more like a traditional debugger where you can step, etc.

Also, in rails you can print things to the log file by calling `logger.debug "String of info"` in your controllers, or by using `<%= debug @instance_variable_to_debug %>` in your views. You can find more info about this in the [ruby guide on debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)